# Vibrational quantum notation

Tags: spectroscopy, notation

Reading articles on spectroscopy I often see this notation:

`30001 <- 01101`, `00011 <- 00001`

in context of molecular vibrational-rotational transitions. 
So I guess each digit in these 5-digit numbers corresponds to a particular quantum number of energy level. 
I need to know what exact quantum numbers does each digit correspond to.